# EF Core 3.1 executesqlInterpolated, how to add out parameter in the query

Tags: parameters, entity-framework-core, out

I expect the EF query below to get the total number of rows through the output parameter `total`, but it doesn't achieve this goal at the moment. How can I re-write this query to get the correct output back?

```
        _dbContext
            .Database
            .ExecuteSqlInterpolated($@"select {total} = count(*) 
                                        from SomeDbSet
                                        where ( columnA like '%{searchedValue1}%' 
                                            or columnB like '%{searchedValue2}%')");
```

Comment: What do tou mean `fail`?

Comment: I expect the output parameter total will return the number of rows filtered but it used to zero, no matter the input parameters were

Comment: Suppose ExecuteSqlInterpolated will automatically convert the raw query to use parameters, a parameter can have a Direction IN or OUT. EF Core translated searchedValue1 and searchedValue2 into IN parameters and they worked fine. But the OUT parameter total didn't, zero was returned. I declare the variables as 
int total = 0;
string searchedValue1 = "something value";
string searchedValue2 = "another value";

Answer (score -2):

You need to declare the total as an output SqlParameter before you can use it in the interpolated query.

```
        SqlParameter total = new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@Total",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        };
```